# Nginx + Tomcat proxyName for more proxies

Tags: nginx, tomcat

I'd like to configure tomcat's proxyName for two domains (jira.firstdomain.com, jira.seconddomain.com) proxied by nginx.

so for first domain I have this configuration in nginx

```
upstream jira {
    server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}

proxy_cache_path        /var/run/nginx-cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=nginx-cache:50m max_size=50m inactive=1440m;
proxy_temp_path         /var/run/nginx-cache/tmp;

server {
    server_name jira.firstdomain.com;
    listen 80;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/jira.log combined;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_set_header Authorization "";

        set $do_not_cache 0;

        if ($request_uri ~* ^(/secure/admin|/plugins|/secure/project)) {
                set $do_not_cache 1;
        }

        proxy_cache nginx-cache;
        proxy_cache_key "$scheme://$host$request_uri";
        proxy_cache_bypass $do_not_cache;
        proxy_cache_valid 1440m;
        proxy_cache_min_uses 1;
        add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
    }

    location ~*/(feed)$ {
        proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control;
    }
}
```

And this configuration in server.xml of tomcat

```
<Connector port="8080"
     maxThreads="150"
     minSpareThreads="25"
     connectionTimeout="20000"

     enableLookups="false"
     maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
     protocol="HTTP/1.1"
     useBodyEncodingForURI="true"
     redirectPort="8443"
     acceptCount="100"
     disableUploadTimeout="true"
                        
     service="http"
     proxyName="jira.firstdomain.com"
     proxyPort="80"/>
```

I'd like to point my second domain to tomcat too. What will I need?

1. Create similar configuration for nginx?
2. Create second connector in tomcat but with another ports and proxyName set to jira.seconddomain.com?

Or is there any simpler setup?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add it to the server_name

```
server_name jira.firstdomain.com jira.seconddomain.com;
```

Of course, this is true as long as you want it to point to the same JIRA instance.

You can safely remove `proxyName="jira.firstdomain.com"` from the connector and it will work, as long as you have `proxy_set_header Host $host;`.

You can also remove `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;` and `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;` from nginx too.

For SSL you either need a certificate with alternate names, either you need to create multiple server blocks.

Comment: yes this is true for nginx. But what about tomcat? Name of proxyName is propagated to request.getServerName(). So now when I use jira.seconddomain.com it will redirect/forward me to jira.firstdomain.com?

Comment: I think you can safely remove `proxyName="jira.firstdomain.com"` from the connector and it will work, as long as you have `proxy_set_header Host $host;`. You can probably remove `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;` and `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;` from nginx too if you do that.

Comment: Ok it looks like it's working, I'm going to mark your answer as correct. Please edit it and add there also notes from your comment above. Additional question - what about certificates and ssl. For different domains I will need different certs. Is it still possible to modify just one nginx config or will I need two separate configs for two domains? Thanks